# Side-Swipeable Gallery of BottomSheets?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, view, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to implement a gallery of summary bottom sheets in Android that are similar to the image below. Is there any way to have multiple bottom sheets attached to one view that you can swipe left/right to switch through and have neighboring views peek from the vertical edges of the screen?

[image: bottom sheet gallery example]
Thanks!

Comment: Transparent `ViewPager`with same instance of a fragment (that will contain the `BottomSheetFragment`). And you should make sure the bottomsheet is always open , so there won't be any miss behavior

Comment: You can take a loot at [ExpandingCollection](https://github.com/Ramotion/expanding-collection-android) that can resolve what you achive easily. And also available for both iOS and Android.

Comment: I believe [this](https://github.com/laenger/ViewPagerBottomSheet) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 5):

In short, use a `ViewPager` as the root element of your `BottomSheetFragment` and initialize the pager adapter with fragment's `getChildSupportFragmentManager();`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

> MapsActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private  final Integer[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.nilesh, R.drawable.nilesh, R.drawable.nilesh, R.drawable.nilesh,
            R.drawable.nilesh, R.drawable.nilesh, R.drawable.nilesh, R.drawable.nilesh};
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;


    private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        Collections.addAll(arrayList, IMAGES);
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetLayout));

        myRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));

        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(this,arrayList));

        SnapHelper helper = new PagerSnapHelper();
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(myRecyclerView);



        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {

                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    //      bottomSheetHeading.setText(getString(R.string.text_collapse_me));
                } else {
                    //     bottomSheetHeading.setText(getString(R.string.text_expand_me));
                }

                switch (newState) {
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                        Log.e("Bottom Sheet Behaviour", "STATE_COLLAPSED");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                        Log.e("Bottom Sheet Behaviour", "STATE_DRAGGING");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                        Log.e("Bottom Sheet Behaviour", "STATE_EXPANDED");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                        Log.e("Bottom Sheet Behaviour", "STATE_HIDDEN");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                        Log.e("Bottom Sheet Behaviour", "STATE_SETTLING");
                        break;
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

> layout.activity_maps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="60dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> DataAdapter

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> imagesArray) {
        this.context = context;
        arrayList = imagesArray;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View imageLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.aa, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(imageLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



        CircleImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            imageView = itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


        }
    }
}
```

> layout.aa

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:src="#919191"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

> **OUTPUTS**

**STATE_COLLAPSED of Bottom Sheet**

[image]

**STATE_EXPANDED of Bottom Sheet**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to have multiple bottom sheets attached to one view that you can swipe

No need To add Multiple Bottomsheets just Add one `BottomSheetFragment` and in this fragment add `ViewPager` > in `ViewPager` adapter ad Data as Your Requirement

Hear is official android site url for more about bottomsheetDialogfragment which can helps Your 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment

Here is simple example https://medium.com/@mujtahidah/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment-android-6ac7dc36e6ac

I hope it Helps